# Guice Deployment exception

Tags: presto, glassfish-4.1.1

In Airpal used Guice for DI framework, in my project we are using glassfish 4.1 payara server RESTful web services, Jersey version 2.21.
issue 1: if use Guice got some runtime exceptions

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator(ValidationInterceptor.java:0) Possible dependencies: - org.apache.bval.cdi.ValidatorBean@33aeb01, - ValidatorBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorBean_default] . Please see server.log for more details.

issue2: if didn't use Guice how can bind airlift client in jersey 2.21 RESTful.

Please help me. anybody know this issue who are using Airpal+presto+glassfish4.1+jersey2.21+maven3.0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since both Guice and standard Java EE CDI use the same `@Inject` annotations, the CDI mechanism is triggered but fails to find dependencies, because your applcation is configured with Guice.

The simplest solution with GlassFish/Payara is to disable implicit CDI when deploying the application (there is a checkbox in Admin console when deploying, or an option to asadmin command).

You can disable CDI in the application archive in a XML descriptor too. Have a look at Payara Server docs about [disabling CDI or filtering CDI scanning](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/content/documentation/extended-documentation/app-deployment/descriptor-elements.html). Note that most options are available only in Payara Server and not in GlassFish 4.1.

The CDI is triggered either by
 - putting `beans.xml` into you application (I don't expect you put it there, because you're using Guice, but check if it wasn't generated by your IDE for some reason)
 - annotating one or more classes with annotations that trigger CDI - e.g. any EJB annotation (`@Stateless`, `@Stateful`,...)